# how to get all wp_postmeta data for a specific meta_key and meta_value?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here I need post_id to update the value of '_stock' in my woo commerce site.

I tried this code,but it's not working.

```
  foreach($allsku as $key=>$val ){

                $alldata = mysql_query("SELECT * from $postmeta_table where `meta_key`='_sku' and `meta_value`=$val");


$data =mysql_fetch_assoc($alldata);

                 $post_id = $data['post_id'];
                 echo $post_id;exit;
                 update_post_meta($post_id,'_stock',$allquantity[$key]); 
}
```

Here $val which contains the value of meta_key i.e sku.What I need is the post id of that sku.But this select query is not working in live but it's working in localhost. Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried doing an actual `WP_Query()`? Unless I'm not understanding, a standard query should work here.

Comment: @rnevius you want me to use this instead of mysql_query?